# gallery with jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery

I built this website giorgiobosisio.com and used the fancybox jquery. I've inserted in few pages and in some is working while in other is not. The code is the following and it's always the same. I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Anyone can help?  Thanks a lot

here are two links:

working:  http://giorgiobosisio.com/pensiero.html (gallery is at the bottom)
not working:  http://giorgiobosisio.com/wind.html

```
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/1.jpg">GALLERY</a>

                        <div class="hidden">
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/2.jpg"><img src="images/Black/2.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/3.jpg"><img src="images/Black/3.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/4.jpg"><img src="images/Black/4.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/5.jpg"><img src="images/Black/5.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/6.jpg"><img src="images/Black/6.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/7.jpg"><img src="images/Black/7.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/8.jpg"><img src="images/Black/8.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/9.jpg"><img src="images/Black/9.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/10.jpg"><img src="images/Black/10.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/11.jpg"><img src="images/Black/11.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/12.jpg"><img src="images/Black/12.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/13.jpg"><img src="images/Black/13.jpg"></a>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="images/Black/14.jpg"><img src="images/Black/14.jpg"></a>      
                        </div>

                    </li>
```

Comment: the one working pull images from `http://giorgiobosisio.com/images/UPK/` but the other from `http://giorgiobosisio.com/images/WTWH/`

Comment: that's right. I made different folders. Fact is, it is working perfectly locally but not on the hosting

Comment: I understand, but the link points to `http://giorgiobosisio.com/images/WTWH/1.jpg`, which doesn't exist (try opening that link in a new window). Make sure the images exist in that folder